# Slow GUI on chemdoodle using AMDGPU-PRO driver with RX470

Tags: drivers, java

I switched from opensuse to ubuntu so I could easily install the AMDGPU-PRO driver for my RX-470 (had no luck getting any drivers to work with it on opensuse). The driver is installed and works a dream in most games, having no issues with it there.

However, when using chemdoodle (a java based application) the GUI is incredibly laggy. I think that this is an issue with my driver configuration because when I use recovery mode (not sure which driver this defaults to) the interface works fine in chemdoodle.

Can anyone offer some insight into what's causing the lagginess, I'm thinking of switching driver while either chemdoodle or amd fix some bugs, but using the radeon driver I was locked at a low resolution...

If you need any more information please say.

Comment: The recovery probably uses the default open-source driver which is either *radeon* or *amdgpu* depending on your hardware. If you could install the Pro one then most likely amdgpu is the default. The thing is AMDGPU-PRO is still beta and issues should be expected.

Comment: Thanks, I'll see if I can switch to amdgpu and get it working at 1080p (in recovery mode the only option was much lower). If I can use the slower driver at native resolution and chemdoodle works I'll be happy.

Comment: What kernel are you using? I believe kernel 4.7 onwards offer more for amdgpu support